# CodeIgniter connect mssql database from another hosting

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework for my application. I need to connect another hosting databse with my application. I have tried as like below but didn't work.

```
$db['intermediate_db']['hostname'] = '45.116.113.98,41433';
$db['intermediate_db']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['intermediate_db']['password'] = '';
$db['intermediate_db']['database'] = 'logimax';
$db['intermediate_db']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['intermediate_db']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['intermediate_db']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['intermediate_db']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['intermediate_db']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['intermediate_db']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$common_db = $this->load->database('intermediate_db', TRUE);
$status    = $common_db->insert('scheme_transaction', $data);
```

I have given the correct credentials only in my config file but showing the error like

> A Database Error Occurred Unable to connect to your database server
>   using the provided settings Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line
>   Number: 1015

I have confirmed with my hosting person can connect another hsoting server by using IP and port number. And also I have enabled mssql extension and checked in php info file also. Could you please help anyone to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `port` key in `database.php`.

```
$db['intermediate_db']['port'] = 41433;

$db['intermediate_db']['hostname'] = '45.116.113.98';
$db['intermediate_db']['port'] = 41433;
$db['intermediate_db']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['intermediate_db']['password'] = '';
$db['intermediate_db']['database'] = 'logimax';
$db['intermediate_db']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['intermediate_db']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['intermediate_db']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['intermediate_db']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['intermediate_db']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['intermediate_db']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I have checked now as like this given the port number separate but still having an issue. Same issue Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Comment: I assume you are also adding the correct password and username for it. Check if the hosting provides a domain name for the mysql server.

Comment: They don't have password for db